# Using boolean functions as pattern discriminators in F#

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, active-pattern

I tried googling this but I couldn't find a collection of words that guided me to what I am trying to do.

I am trying to solve [Project Euler Problem 54](https://projecteuler.net/problem=54), and I have this rather ridiculous function:

```
let evaluate hand =
    if isRoyalFlush hand then 9
    elif isStraightFlush hand then 8
    elif isFour hand then 7
    elif isFullHouse hand then 6
    elif isFlush hand then 5
    elif isStraight hand then 4
    elif isThree hand then 3
    elif isTwoPair hand then 2
    elif isPair hand then 1
    else 0
```

All the `isSomething` keywords are functions that take a `string array` and return a Boolean. Is there a more elegant way of doing this using pattern matching ?

This doesn't work:

```
match true with
| isRoyalFlush hand -> 9
| isStraightFlush hand -> 8
// .. etc
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
match hand with 
| isRoyalFlush -> 9
| isStraightFlush -> 8
// .. etc
```

I remember seeing something like that at one point but I can't remember where or how to find it.

Comment: Active patterns is what you want

Comment: The active pattern approach looks slightly nicer but requires lots of boilerplate above it. I prefer the answer from @FuleSnabel which just uses higher order functions and data. But actually, I think your code is just fine as it is and perfectly understandable. Adding some column alignment might make it less likely to be accidentally broken in future.

Comment: I am also of the opinion that there is nothing especially wrong with the code posted by OP.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [active patterns](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/convenience-active-patterns/):

```
let (|IsRoyalFlush|_|) hand =
    if isRoyalFlush hand then Some () else None

let (|IsStraightFlush|_|) hand =
    if isStraightFlush hand then Some() else None

// etc.

match hand with
| IsRoyalFlush -> 9
| IsStraightFlush -> 8
// etc.
```

Or better, pull out all that common code into a simple active-pattern builder:

```
let toActivePattern pred x =
    if pred x then Some () else None

let (|IsRoyalFlush|_|) = isRoyalFlush |> toActivePattern
let (|IsStraightFlush|_|) = isStraightFlush |> toActivePattern
// etc.

match hand with
| IsRoyalFlush -> 9
| IsStraightFlush -> 8
// etc.
```

If you don't understand how that second example works, leave a comment and I'll go into more depth.

### Composing active patterns together

Since active patterns are just functions, you can use standard function composition to join them together. Well, *almost* standard function composition. Normal function composition with the `>>` operator means "take the *result* of function 1, and use it as the input to function 2". But here, function 1 and function 2 both return `Some ()`, but take an int; you can't pass the output of 1 into the input of 2, since they aren't compatible types. But what we want is actually to pass the same *input* to both functions, and combine their output.

So instead of using normal function composition, we'll define our own function that takes two active patterns, and returns `Some ()` if both patterns match the input:

```
let matchesBoth pattern1 pattern2 x =
  match pattern1 x with
  | None -> None
  | Some _ -> pattern2 x
```

And while we're at it, let's define a custom operator so you can see how that works. This `matchesBoth` function works very much like the `&&` operator, in that it will return `Some ()` only if *both* patterns would return `Some ()` for any given input `x`. We shouldn't overload the `&&` operator to take a different type, so let's create a custom operator that looks like `&&`, but reminds us that it's combining two active patterns. If our operator looks like `|&&|`, that should be perfect. So let's create it:

```
let (|&&|) = matchesBoth
```

That's it! Now we can do something like:

```
let (|Div3|_|) n =
  if n % 3 = 0 then Some () else None

let (|Div5|_|) n =
  if n % 5 = 0 then Some () else None

let (|Div15|_|) = (|Div3|_|) |&&| (|Div5|_|)

let fizzbuzz n =
    match n with
    | Div15 -> "FizzBuzz"
    | Div5 -> "Buzz"
    | Div3 -> "Fizz"
    | _ -> string n

fizzbuzz 30  // Result: "FizzBuzz"
fizzbuzz 31  // Result: "31"
```

Or, for your example:

```
let (|IsStraightFlush|_|) = (|IsStraight|_|) |&&| (|IsFlush|_|)
```

Comment: Thanks, I suspected as much. Somewhat tangent question, though: I tried rewriting my predicates as Active Patterns instead (to return Some and None) but then I couldn't figure out if it is possible to combine two Active Patterns together. Is such a thing possible without hacky code ?

Comment: In other words, is there another way of doing this : `let (|IsStraightFlush|_|) hand = if ((|IsFlush|_|) hand |> Option.isSome) && ((|IsStraight|_|) hand |> Option.isSome) then Some () else None ` ?

Comment: @asibahi - I've edited my answer to answer your second question about combining two active patterns.

Answer (score 8):

Active patterns is certainly an alternative but I sometimes use a table of functions and values:

```
let handScores = 
  [|
  //Which hand?       Score
    isRoyalFlush    , 9
    isStraightFlush , 8
    isFour          , 7
    isFullHouse     , 6
    isFlush         , 5
    isStraight      , 4
    isThree         , 3
    isTwoPair       , 2
    isPair          , 1
    (fun _ -> true) , 0 // Matches all hands
  |]
let handScore hand = 
  handScores 
  |> Array.pick (fun (t, s) -> if t hand then Some s else None)
```